# A tensor category need not be isomorphic to a strict tensor category

Tags: category-theory, homology-cohomology, tensor-products, monoidal-categories, higher-category-theory

I'm reading the book "Tensor categories" by Etingoff (and others). In remark 2.8.6 (posted below), it is claimed that the category $\mathcal{C}_G^\omega$ (defined in example 2.3.8, also below) is not isomorphic to a strict tensor category whenever $\omega$ is not cohomologically trivial. Can someone explain this a bit more?

If someone knows another example of a tensor category that is not isomorphic to a strict tensor category, I'm also interested in that.

---

[image]

Edit: When no answer is given here after the bounty period ends, I will post this question on MO.

Comment: Take a skeleton of any monoidal category with a non-strict skeleton.